# How to prevent cocoa application from freezing?

Tags: cocoa, macos

```
-(void)test
{
  int i;
  for (i=0;i < 1000000;i++)
  {
    //do lengthly operation
  }
}
```

How to prevent its GUI from freezing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bottom line;  don't block the main thread and, thus, don't block the main event loop.

Now, you *could* spawn a thread.  But that isn't actually the correct way write concurrent programs on Mac OS X.

Instead, use [NSOperation and NSOperationQueue.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html)  It is specifically designed to support your concurrent programming needs, it scales well, and NSOperationQueue is tightly integrated into the system such that it will control concurrency based on system resources available (# of cores, CPU load from other applications, etc) more efficiently than *any* direct use of threads.

See also the [Threaded Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would do the lengthy operation in a separate thread,  using NSThread